# How to I set up Socat to relay data between rapberry pi and Windows using cygwin via ethernet

Tags: windows, cygwin, raspberry-pi, ethernet, socat

I have downloaded SoCat via Cygwin on my windows device and have downloaded it on my Raspberry Pi.
What commands should I be using to relay data between the two devices.
I don't want to relay any complicated data, I just want to be able to set up a connection via ethernet between the two devices for now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(Not 100% sure what are you asking, but assuming the simplest case...)

1. Setup IP networking on the ethernet interfaces of both devices.
2. Ensure it works (e.g. `ping <ipAddressPi>` works from windows and `ping <ipAddressWindows>` works from the Raspberry Pi)
3. Run a simple TCP server on windows by using:

   `socat TCP4-LISTEN:12396 -`
4. Run a simple TCP client on Raspberry Pi by using:

   `socat TCP4:<ipAddressWindows>:12396 -`
5. You are done...everything you type on one side gets written on the other side